# including a servlet from another servlet using request dispatcher not working

Tags: java, servlets

`dispatcher.include()` not working

I am trying to include a `servlet` which includes a side `navbar`. It has worked when I included it in another `servlet`. But it doesn't seem to work on this one.

`addItem` is the class in which i want to include the servlet sidenav:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        operations operations=new operations();

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher;


        writer.println("<body>");

        dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("sidenav");
        dispatcher.include(request,response);

        writer.println("<h1> Add new Item</h1>");

        writer.println("<body>");
    }
```

And `sidenav` class looks like this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        PrintWriter writer=response.getWriter();



        writer.println("<div class='sidenav'>");

        writer.println("<div class='item'>");
        writer.println("<a href='addUser'>Add new user</a>");
        writer.println("</div>");

        writer.println("<div class='item'>");
        writer.println("<a href='addInventory'>Add to inventory</a>");
        writer.println("</div>");

        writer.println("<div class='item'>");
        writer.println("<a href='viewReport'>View report</a>");
        writer.println("</div>");

        writer.println("<div class='item'>");
        writer.println("<a href='recordSale'>Record sold items</a>");
        writer.println("</div>");

        writer.println("<div class='item'>");
        writer.println("<a href='addItem'>Add new item</a>");
        writer.println("</div>");

        writer.println("<div class='item'>");
        writer.println("<a href='dayEnd'>Do day end</a>");
        writer.println("</div>");

        writer.println("<div class='item'>");
        writer.println("<a href='monthEnd'>Do month end</a>");
        writer.println("</div>");

        writer.println("<div class='item'>");
        writer.println("<a href='yearEnd'>Do year end</a>");
        writer.println("</div>");

        writer.println("</div>");

    }
```

`sidenav servlet` is called from the class `managerHome` which looks like this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        PrintWriter writer= response.getWriter();

        operations operations=new operations();

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("headerHtml");
        dispatcher.include(request,response);


        writer.println("<body>");

        dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("sidenav");
        dispatcher.include(request,response);

        HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
        String user= (String) session.getAttribute("user");

        writer.println("<div class='main'>");
        writer.println("<h1>Welcome back"+user+"</h1>");
        writer.println("</div>");

        writer.println("</body>");


    }
```

As you see I have included the sidenav servlet from the managerHome servlet and it work's fine

I am expecting the side navigation to appear in the addItem page but it does not seem to work.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I have figured out my problem. I was trying to include `sidenav` which has `doGet()` from  `addItem` which has `doPost()`. Apparently you can not send request or include a servlet from a servlet that do not have the same overridden method.